# How to embed a ember handler inside the tag of bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

i have a index.html page inside that we have a following line of code for opening a bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="registration.html" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>
```

so on the click of 'Click me' i want the registration.html to be opened inside the 'modal-content'.

lets see the code inside the registration.html:

```
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  
</button>
 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Matrix Registration</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <form class="form-horizontal b1">
   <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <div class="row">
       <span>Hello, <strong>{{welcomefirstName}} {{welcomelastName}}</strong>!</span>
     </div>
   </script>
  </form>
 </div>
```

while clicking the click me the modal is opening but the ember tag({{welcomefirstName}}) rendering is not working so i am not getting the actual values for handle bars instead getting only the place holders as it is.

any suggestions will be helpfull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to open the modal with the bootstrap js script ?

If so, that's not how I would do it :

There is a pretty good example here http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Basically, you want to put a named outlet on your "index"

```
{{outlet 'modal'}}
```

and declare an "openModal" action on your route which will "attach" your modal template to the outlet.

Comment: Thanks mate thats really helpfull,  but how we can open an another HTML file inside that modal:

Comment: Are we still talking about an ember application ?